# Public Key exchange between iOS and Java

Tags: java, ios, rsa, public-key, commoncrypto

I would like to share a public key generated on an iPhone/iPad with an Java based Server or an Android device. On the Java side (Server or Android) I would like to use `java.security` and `libcommonCrypto` (the SecKeyRef stuff) on iOS.

I've got everything working except the public key exchange between these two platforms. By using `SecItemCopyMatching` I can only export the public key into some format not supported by anything else then Apple. With Java I can load public keys as X509 certificate (through `java.security.X509EncodedKeySpec`) or as module and exponent (through `java.security.RSAPublicKeySpec`).

Now I need to know how to export a `SecKeyRef` as X509 certificate or (what I guess is the easier solution) get the module and exponent from it. And I also need the way backwards.

Here is some sample public key loaded from a `SecKeyRef` and encoded to BASE64:

```
MIGJAoGBAMYgXP6rvD/Y8F0VQE0HvxpVnnOxXYl5TDlOfW/leyrCLWGWg9Jp+Tl9dYvK/zWgNpoEfFzMVRpUk9UHcIaDWHW3g0BpS2MVC3Vs/0e2eu6S2WMGHpzqcJB51jJRbnqXQ23nVKC2YE520Po3EvFyTr8MlFJqTCJrovgc7fze4RI5AgMBAAE=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol Apples `libcommonCrypto` is using is described in [RFC3347](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) and is the modulus and public exponent as a ASN.1 sequence.

> An RSA public key should be represented with the ASN.1 type RSAPublicKey:
>
> ```
>   RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
>       modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
>       publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
>   }
> ```

Quote from RFC3347, Ver. 2.1, A.1.1